# Windows 7 compatible old graphics tablet. Can I get it to work on Win10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, adobe-photoshop, graphics-tablet

My graphics tablet is a really old one: Trust TB-4200. It had drivers for Windows 7 and I could use it with no problems then, but like a fool I rushed to upgrade to Windows 10. The device still figures out the resolution of my screen so the cursor follows the pen nicely, but without a Win10 driver, I can't utilize its pen pressure feature, which is critical to making digital images. And I can't go back to Windows 7 now because I didn't have it on disk and I don't want to wipe my drives.

Can I somehow retrieve the pen pressure information and give that data to the programs I use like SAI or Photoshop?

Comment: Windows 10 supports rolling back your installation for 30 days.  In a general sense if the hardware vendor does not offer Windows 10 drivers then you really only have one choice, to install Windows 7, so you can install the required drivers for pressure sensitivity with the pen.

Comment: Have you tried installing the drivers? Many Windows 7 drivers will still work on Windows 10. You can also try running the installer in Compatibility mode for Windows 7.